# Trying to add the Latin American Spanish keyboard layout on IBus for Debian Bulleye in MATE, but I only get Spaniard Spanish

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, ibus

I am running Debian 11 Bullseye for AMD64 on an HP Pavillion Touch 14-N009LA laptop, using IBus and MATE as desktop environment, having upgraded recently from Buster. Prior to upgrading point release, I could use the Latin American keyboard layout with IBus; afterwards, I am no longer able to do so.

The Keyboard Preferences app on MATE Control Center shows the Latin American Spanish layout, and I can manually set it with `setxkbmap latam` on a terminal (before IBus kicks in and replaces it), but on IBus I am only presented with the "Spanish" keyboard, which corresponds to the Spaniard Spanish keyboard that has different punctuation keys; there is no option for "Latin American" or anything similar.

Running `ibus list-engine` gives me the following output, in which I can't see the Latin American Spanish layout, and no matches for `latam` or anything similar:

```
<irrelevant languages omitted>
language: Spanish
  xkb:es:nodeadkeys:spa - Spanish (no dead keys)
  xkb:es:sundeadkeys:spa - Spanish (Sun dead keys)
  xkb:es:winkeys:spa - Spanish (Windows)
  xkb:es:dvorak:spa - Spanish (Dvorak)
  xkb:es:deadtilde:spa - Spanish (dead tilde)
  xkb:es:mac:spa - Spanish (Macintosh)
  xkb:es::spa - Spanish
<irrelevant languages omitted>
```

So far I could only find [a guide that only seems to apply to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014585/how-to-add-a-latin-american-keyboard-in-17-10), and [the Arch Linux guide for IBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IBus#Other_desktop_environments).

The former guide suggested that maybe I had to generate a Spanish locale for my system, which I did by uncommenting the `es-MX` locales from `/etc/locale.gen` and then running `locale-gen`. Afterwards, I rebooted my system. It didn't work.

Any other idea on how could I use the Latin American Spanish layout on IBus for Debian Bullseye?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE.** I've found that [the latest commit in the IBus source](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/16df64edadc21f50906e5442b73425b9256fbf65/engine/denylist.txt) has the blacklist already implemented, and that *all Latin American layouts are blacklisted by default*.

This affects the generation process, which is done with a Python script on build time, which in turn, sources the available X layouts from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, [as this comment clearly states](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2322#issuecomment-1027763150).

The exact commit on which this restriction was implemented [is here](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/568d58dfadefa801b96058c1155daecff3d51605). As for the reason why this was done, is honestly beyond me, and until this situation is properly addressed, the fix I propose below must be applied *every time IBus is updated* (as stated [in this previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242981)).

---

I've faced the same problem in Xubuntu 22.04, and recently used a workaround that involves editing a whitelist.

Even though it's been suggested that [IBus 1.5.23 would include a blacklist, in place of the currently used whitelist](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/IBus_1.5.23), so that engines added would automatically appear as selectable layouts, it seems this feature is yet to be implemented (I have version 1.5.26 right now).

What I did to make it work is as follows:

1. Open the file `/usr/share/ibus/component/simple.xml` using `sudo`, and your editor of choice.
2. Locate the `xkb:es::spa` engine. In my machine, it looks like this:

```xml
<engine>
    <name>xkb:es::spa</name>
    <language>es</language>
    <license>GPL</license>
    <author>Peng Huang &lt;shawn.p.huang@gmail.com&gt;</author>
    <layout>es</layout>
    <longname>Spanish</longname>
    <description>Spanish</description>
    <icon>ibus-keyboard</icon>
    <rank>50</rank>
</engine>
```

3. Once found, copy the `<engine>` tag and paste it beside it (as a sibling, on the same level), and change the following tag values:

   - `name`, from `xkb:es::spa` to `xkb:latam::spa`.
   - `layout`, from `es` to `latam`.
   - `longname`, to any text of your choice so that you can distinguish it from other layouts.

It should now look like this:

```xml
<!-- I added this one. vvv -->
<engine>
    <name>xkb:latam::spa</name>
    <language>es</language>
    <license>GPL</license>
    <author>logo_writer</author>
    <layout>latam</layout>
    <longname>Spanish Latam</longname>
    <description>Spanish Latam</description>
    <icon>ibus-keyboard</icon>
    <rank>50</rank>
</engine>
<!-- I added this one. ^^^ -->

<engine>
    <name>xkb:es::spa</name>
    <language>es</language>
    <license>GPL</license>
    <author>Peng Huang &lt;shawn.p.huang@gmail.com&gt;</author>
    <layout>es</layout>
    <longname>Spanish</longname>
    <description>Spanish</description>
    <icon>ibus-keyboard</icon>
    <rank>50</rank>
</engine>
```

4. Once the new engine is added, save the file.
5. Restart the IBus service, by issuing the command `ibus restart`.
6. Once IBus restarts, type `ibus list-engine` and check that the new engine appears in the list.

In my machine, I have the following configurations. The one I added is `Spanish Latam`.

```plaintext
$ ibus list-engine | grep -A 7 Espa
idioma: Español
  xkb:es:nodeadkeys:spa - Spanish (no dead keys)
  xkb:es:winkeys:spa - Spanish (Windows)
  xkb:es:dvorak:spa - Spanish (Dvorak)
  xkb:es:deadtilde:spa - Spanish (dead tilde)
  xkb:latam::spa - Spanish Latam
  xkb:es:mac:spa - Spanish (Macintosh)
  xkb:es::spa - Spanish
```

7. Using `ibus-setup` or `ibus engine`, set the layout to the one you previosuly created. At this point, it should work.

I hope this works for you. :)

Comment: It worked me perfectly (Arch Linux 2022 :3) Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but just now I had to deal with this again. And indeed, it worked flawlessly. Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 2):

I just removed all the keyboards from the **Ibus Preferences** and then run the command: **setxkbmap latam** in the terminal.

Comment: I will upvote but not check this answer. It is more of a workaround than an actual solution. However, experience has shown me that you never know when an actual solution cannot be implemented and a hack must be done...